# How to format Android date without year and display month and day according to local settings?

Tags: android, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android get current time and date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date)

From this [Format date without year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790918/format-date-without-year) I know how to get rid of year.

But I also want to formate month and day.
if user set 09/24/2012, it displays 09/24;
if user set 24/09/2012, it displays 24/09.

And I also wanna support l18n.

Maybe the solution is combine DateFormat and DateUtils, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date
Did you look into this.

Comment: Maybe that's not I want. Actually I got a long and wanna format it to date and used int TextView.setText(). I found a function DateFormat.getDateFormatOrder(), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: If the question is on whether to display the M/D over D/M, just do D/M, most countries use D/M/Y

Comment: Here is my 'locale aware' solution 

DateFormat dateFormatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG); // use MEDIUM or SHORT according to your needs

String date = dateFormatter.format(now);

// remove year
String year = String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));
date = date.replace(year, "").trim();

will output "13 décembre" in French
:-)

Comment: Missing line in my solution: Date now = new Date(); ... of course

Comment: Fun fact: this question is really not a duplicate.  Yes, we all know how to get a specifically-formatted date.  That's not what this question is asking.

It looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790918/format-date-without-year would actually work, since android.text.format.DateFormat uses SimpleDateFormats.  That's still way ugly, though.

Answer (score -2):

First split the information into variables, then just display as needed.

```
public String formatDate(String date)
{
    int index1, index2;

    index1 = date.indexOf('/');
    index2 = date.lastIndexOf('/');

    String str1, str2, str3;

    str1 = date.substring(0, index1);
    str2 = date.substring(index1 + 1, index2);
    str3 = date.substring(index2);

    // Presuming that str1 is the month and str2 is the day ...

    return str1 + "/" + str2;
}
```

Comment: This will fail miserably on all devices where locale is set to format date in other than american forms (like 24.10.1998 or some such).

Comment: I would assume the individual who would use this code would be intelligent enough to know that.